# How to run an exe file with VBA Excel 2016 for Mac

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I have some python code that I've converted to an executable file and need to run from an excel macro (I'm using Excel 2016 on a Mac).

I'm trying to run it as follows:

```
Sub RUN_JENSEN()

    Shell ("/Users/DanielJackson1/Desktop/auto-py-to-exe-master/output/Wakes/Wakes.exe" & "/Users/DanielJackson1/PycharmProjects/Wakes/Wakes.py")

End Sub
```

but I get the error

> Run-time error '76':
>   Path not found

I am 100% certain the both paths are correct, so has anybody else had this problem or have any suggestions?

Thanks, Dan

Comment: Try replacing `&` with `& " " &`

Answer (score 3):

`&` in VBA is string concatenation, so your code is basically

```
Shell ("/Users/DanielJackson1/Desktop/auto-py-to-exe-master/output/Wakes/Wakes.exe/Users/DanielJackson1/PycharmProjects/Wakes/Wakes.py")
```

which probably is not a valid path.

You cannot run `exe` files on a Mac (unless you have something installed) by the way, and since it looks like the exe file is basically the python file compiled, why not just use the Python interpreter and run `Wakes.py`?

Comment: Ah ok - I was just copying the line of code that was given to me by somebody at work who said that's what they used on their Windows so I assumed it was something to do with that. When you say python interpreter, is that something that runs through VBA?

Comment: `Shell()` is basically the same as typing a command into the terminal, so Python interpreter runs through VBA as well.